# How to use facebook signup and login or connect into my asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook

can any one give me a best example site URL to using how to use facebook connect or facebook signup into my site or facebook login with asp.net site?

actually my requirement is that when i registered into my asp.net site by using facebook at that time we want to get facebook user's username (emailid) from facebook and firstname and last name also with user image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use facebook javascript SDK because by using javascript SDK you can do anythin on facebook easily.
I am given you some code example to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({
            appId: '012341352533212',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
            channelUrl: 'http://www.xyz.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
    </script>
```

this code call your facebook application

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function facebookLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        jQuery('#txtFirstName').val(response.first_name);
                        jQuery('#txtLastName').val(response.last_name);
                        jQuery('#txtEmail').val(response.email);
                        jQuery('#hdfUID').val(response.id);
                        //                        FB.logout(function (response) {
                        //                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    jQuery('#txtFirstName').val('');
                    jQuery('#txtLastName').val('');
                    jQuery('#txtEmail').val('');
                    jQuery('#hdfUID').val('');
                }
            }, { scope: 'email' });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

and this code call login page of facebook and it response you get back userid, first name. last name and email of the particular user and by using jquery save these values in textbox or hiddenfield and get these values on server side code page.

Answer (score 4):

Here i am going to write step by step procedure for this.

1. You need to login into developers section of fb using this [link.](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Create New Application by clicking this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
3. Write Name of your required application i.e login , test etc etc as you can see it from screen shot given below
4. Fill the necessary text box values , please see screen shot for this,
   Now you are done with steps of making login application on developers account , open visual studio and make a page of asp.net with extension of aspx in visual studio.
5. copy and paste below code of javascript into head section of your page.

```
<script>
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '155578484623690', // Write your own application id
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
            scope: 'id,name,gender,user_birthday,email',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    if (me.name) {
                        document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                        document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
                        document.getElementById('BD').innerHTML = me.birthday;
                        document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
                        document.getElementById('Gender').innerHTML = me.gender;
                    }
                })
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
    }
</script>
```

6. Copy and paste given below html in body section of your html page

   ```
     <div style="height: 500px; margin-left: 23px;">
               <h1>
                   Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
               <div id="auth-status">
                   <div id="auth-loggedout">
                       <div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">
                           Login with Facebook</div>
                   </div>
                   <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
                       Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
                       <br />
                       Email: <span id="Email"></span><br/> Ammar's Birthday <span id="BD"></span><br/>
                       Gender :<span id="Gender"></span><br/>
                       <br />
                       Profile Image:
                       <img id="profileImg" />
                   </div>
               </div>
       </div>
   ```

Now run your asp.net page and you will get your required Information. 
Here i got display name,birthday , email address, gender and image

see final screen shot and enjoy with this in your own way :)

[image]

[image: Write name of Application]

[image: Fill Necessary Text Boxes]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look here for an open source project that does what you are looking for:

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=facebook%20api&ac=3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Javascript SDK on your web page.

The following solution uses the xocialCore plugin available here.  You can actually just extract the first two functions from this plugin as they provide the necessary functions for this.

https://github.com/xocialhost/jquery.xocialCore.js/blob/master/jquery.xocialCore.js

First you'll need to create and configure a facebook application.  Make sure you fill in the website information with your URL/Domain.

On your registration page make sure you've included jQuery and then the above plugin.

Create a button on your page like:

```
<button id="fbLoginButton">Login</button>
```

and then implement the following code:

```
$.xcInitFacebook({appId:'yourFBappId',callback:function(){

   $('#fbLoginButton').click(function(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      $.xcFbLogin({permissions:'manage_pages, offline_access, email',callback:function(){

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                var fbUrl='https://graph.facebook.com/'+response.authResponse.userID+
                          '?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture'+
                           '&access_token='+response.authResponse.accessToken;

        $.getJSON(fbUrl,function(data){
                     //Pass the return data information to your Registration/Login system
                });


            }); 

      } }); 

   });

} });
```

The response back from the Facebook server should be something like:

```
{
 "email": "emailid\u0040domain.com",
 "first_name": "fName",
 "last_name": "lName",
 "id": "12345",
 "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49860_12345_8441_q.jpg"
}
```

You'd obviously want to take this farther where you'd check to see if the user was already logged in and then show the login button or not but this should get you the requested user info.